# Install Referrer in Flutter from Google Ads

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-ads-api, firebase-dynamic-links, install-referrer

Is there a way in Flutter to get the install referrer from google play? 
https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library.html
if possible both Android and iOS.

My Goal is to identify if the user was installed/downloaded from Play Store Search, on our Website, and in our Google Ads.
For our Play Store Search and on Our Website Download/Install is already handled by Firebase Dynamic Links.

My Current Problem was about the Google Ads Universal App Campaign. I can't attach links in Universal App Campaign.

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling with this as well. You can solve it partly with dynamic links but the install referrer is a bit trickier... Let me know if you get to the bottom of this!